# Using replace() replaces too much content

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm replacing `t` by `g`when `t` is not followed by the letter `p` using this line of code:

```
"tpto".replace(/(t)[^p]/g, "g");
```

However, the result is `tpg` and I was expecting `tpgo`. As I don't know which letter will follow the `t` I need something dynamic but I don't know what to do, any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"tpto".replace(/t(?!p)/g, "g");
// => "tpgo"
```

- `/t(?!p)/`: `t` will match only if it is not (negative) followed (lookahead) by `p`.